Spring fails bean creation from unspecified package
I've created an artifact "MyElectricity-aWattar" which deals with a MariaDB database on behalf of MyBatis. It works fine.
The is also another artifact "MyElectricity-Sungrow" which needs methods from "MyElectricity-aWattar", so this artifact is defined as a dependency to "MyElectricity-Sungrow".
All classes are instantiated by Spring. This means the DAO and the Mapper are meant to be instantiated - but this fails with cause
No qualifying bean of type 'de.gombers.electricity.mybatis.awattar.mappers.aWattarMapper' available

I do not understand why this fails. The Mapper is defined with the MyBatis @Mapper-Annotation - and works fine if intatiation is done when starting a @SpringBootApplication from "MyElectricity-aWattar".
I tried to skip instantiation of the DAO by not specifying the DAO-package to the @ComponenScan-Annotation.
it looks like this:
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"de.gombers.modbus.sungrow", "de.gombers.electricity.awattar"})

while the DAO and the Mapper are maintained in package de.gombers.electricity.mybatis.awattar".
But nevertheless, I see the error:
Error creating bean with name 'aWattarDAO' defined in file [E:\$SysProg\GIT\MyHome\MyElectricity\MyElectricity-AWattar\target\classes\de\gombers\electricity\mybatis\awattar\mappers\aWattarDAO.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'de.gombers.electricity.mybatis.awattar.mappers.aWattarMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

So I have two questions left:

Why does instantiation of the Mapper fail
Why does instantiation of the DAO even occur - though its package does not match the

I'm runing with Java 17, Maven 3.9.9, Spring 3.4.0 an myBatis 3.5.4

Sorry - there were typo errors in my code. I'm on this problem for hours now and did not see it - until yet
